# Optimize $f(x,y,z)=x^2y^2z^2$ subject to $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ using Lagrange multiplier

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I was trying to find min/max for $f(x,y,z)=x^2y^2z^2$ subject to $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.
I´m working with Stewart's *Calculus*, and I haven´t seen yet second order conditions.

I found out that the function has 9 critical points at $\left(\frac{1}{3}^{1/2},\frac{1}{3}^{1/2},\frac{1}{3}^{1/2}\right)$ (the values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ could be positive or negative). Those are clearly max.

Then I checked on [this website](https://www.aplustopper.com/stewart-calculus-7e-solutions-chapter-14-partial-derivatives-exercise-14-8/) that has every Stewart solution, and there the point $(0,0,0)$ is shown as a minimum. Is that correct? Why? It doesn't satisfy $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

Comment: What is the number of the exercise?

Comment: Section 14.8, exercise 10.

Comment: I see there the Answer 10E, which is the answer to a problem similar, but not identical to yours. Anyway, it also mentions the point $(0,0,0)$, which does not belong to the surface mentioned at the problem. It seems silly to me.

Comment: Point $(0, 0, 0)$ cannot be the minimum for the given constraint but the min value of the function is clearly $0$.

Comment: Yes, that answer is incorrect as I suspected. Thank you.

Comment: Minimum is at any point where x or y or z is 0.